# Underline in Ruby Report

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruport

Hey all,
I'm trying a very simple thing here in Ruport but I don't seem able to get it working.
All I want is underline a part of a text.
I already have the substring that I want to underline, because i thought `<u></u>` would do the trick (`<i> and <b>` work)
Anybody got a working solution for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="underline"></span>
```

and in css:

```
.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
```